# controls upon unfocued window doesn't effect on first click

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, window

Et least two clicks should be done to click some control on unfocused window. Window gets focus on first click and then control gets MouseClick message on second.

Question: Is there possibility to click control on unfocused window by first click?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in WPF. I've noticed similar issue with Popup: first click on control outside of popup is closing the popup, but does nothing to the clicked control.

Answer (score 1):

Just how I'd imagine doing it :

Subscribe to the MouseLeftButtonDown of the parent control, or the outer grid or whatever, then utilize the MouseButtonEventArgs, which have a Target property telling you who it's currently clicking.

Then do whatever clicking the element you wanted clicked yourself ;-)